# Error during merging of index in Solr

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 6.5.1

I have encountered the below error during the merging of the 3.5TB of index. What could be the cause that lead to this?

I am using the IndexMergeTool from Solr, from the command below:

```
java -classpath lucene-core-6.5.1.jar;lucene-misc-6.5.1.jar org.apache.lucene.misc.IndexMergeTool
```

The heap size is 32GB. There are more than 20 million documents in the two cores. There are only 1 host, 1 nodes and 1 shard for these 3.5TB. The merging has been running for more than 48 hours before hitting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Lucene Merge Thread #8" java.io.
IOException: background merge hit exception: _6f(6.5.1):C7256757 _6e(6.5.1):C646
2072 _6d(6.5.1):C3750777 _6c(6.5.1):C2243594 _6b(6.5.1):C1015431 _6a(6.5.1):C105
0220 _69(6.5.1):c273879 _28(6.4.1):c79011/84:delGen=84 _26(6.4.1):c44960/8149:de
  lGen=100 _29(6.4.1):c73855/68:delGen=68 _5(6.4.1):C46672/31:delGen=31 _68(6.5.1)
:c66 into _6g [maxNumSegments=1]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.forceMerge(IndexWriter.java:1931)

        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.forceMerge(IndexWriter.java:1871)

        at org.apache.lucene.misc.IndexMergeTool.main(IndexMergeTool.java:57)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The requested operation could not be completed d
ue to a file system limitation
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput$1.write(FSDirectory
.java:419)
        at java.util.zip.CheckedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.OutputStreamIndexOutput.writeBytes(OutputStre
amIndexOutput.java:53)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedIndexOutput.writeBytes(RateLimited
IndexOutput.java:73)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.DataOutput.writeBytes(DataOutput.java:52)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.ForUtil.writeBlock(ForUtil.java:175
)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50PostingsWriter.addPosition(
Lucene50PostingsWriter.java:286)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.PushPostingsWriterBase.writeTerm(PushPosting
sWriterBase.java:156)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter$TermsWriter.w
rite(BlockTreeTermsWriter.java:866)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.blocktree.BlockTreeTermsWriter.write(BlockTr
eeTermsWriter.java:344)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.FieldsConsumer.merge(FieldsConsumer.java:105
)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsWriter
.merge(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:164)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:2
16)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:101)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4353
)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3928)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMe
rgeScheduler.java:624)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(Conc
urrentMergeScheduler.java:661)
org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.IOException: The req
uested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException
(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:703)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(Conc
urrentMergeScheduler.java:683)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The requested operation could not be completed d
ue to a file system limitation
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Unknown Source)
```

Regards,
Edwin

Answer (score 3):

is this a Windows host?

the merging operation is hitting some issue with the file system, as the index is 3.5TB some of the files might be quite big, so depending on the version of Windows you might be hitting one of those limits.

Things you can do:

1. make sure this is false (so the whole index is put in multiple, not one file) in solrconfig.xml

   ```
   <useCompoundFile>false</useCompoundFile>
   ```
2. merge down to 2 or 3 segment (if you are merging into 1):

   &maxSegments=2
3. try defragmenting your disk
4. upgrade to a later version of Windows Server, file size limits etc will be larger with every new version
5. move to linux

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2, and the disk was on the SSD disk formatted in NTFS.